# icons in html page

Tags: html, css, icons

I'm totally new in html and planned to design a personal web page. The following is the code I wrote. Everything is fine and the only problem I have is about two icons I used: icon-user and icon-book. The problem is that it does not show up in the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" js no-touch csstransitions" style="" lang="en"><head>
    <title>Vahid: Homepage</title>
    <!--CSS styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/font-awesome.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/perfect-scrollbar-0.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/style.css">
    <link id="theme-style" rel="stylesheet" href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/default.css">
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="Vahid%20::%20Homepage_files/jquery.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body data-twttr-rendered="true">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <a href="#sidebar" class="mobilemenu"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div class="ps-container" id="main-nav">
                <div id="nav-container">
                    <div id="profile" class="clearfix">
                        <div class="portrate hidden-xs"></div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <h2>Vahid</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="navigation">
                        <li class="currentmenu">
                            <a href="Vahid :: Homepage.html">
                                <div class="icon icon-user"></div>
                                <div class="text">About Me</div>
                            </a>
                        </li>  
                        <li>
                            <a href="Vahid :: Research.html">
                                <div class="icon icon-book"></div>
                                <div class="text">Research</div>
                            </a>
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    <iframe style="display: none;" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" id="rufous-sandbox" frameborder="0"></iframe></body></html>
```

and both icons are clearly defined font-awesome.css

```
.icon-user:before{content:"\f007";}
.icon-book:before{content:"\f02d";}
```

It would be great if you guys can help.

Comment: Hi, font awesome uses those classes -> "fa" (instead of "icon") and for example "fa-book" (instead of "icon-book"). Try to use it in your code and check what will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<i class="fa fa-book"></i>` 
to simplify Kamils response.

You can place i into another div, you will have less issues that way.

EX: `<div class="text"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> About Me</div>`.

Copy and paste that.  I recommend you always use the i tag to place icons.  You can place them in most html tags such as headers.

`<h1><i class="fa fa-magnet"></i> This is a magnent</h1>`

Check out http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icons/ for an alternative methods.

If you are new to bootstrap, check out http://bootsnipp.com/
This is a great reference for code snippets.

If you are using Bootstrap 3, check out this link http://getbootstrap.com/components/
You will read about glyphicons here.

Glyphicons now come with Bootstrap and you may find glyphicons more appropriate at times.